# OpenCV crash when attempting to capture default iSight camera

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to get openCV running on my Macbook Pro (10.8.5, retina model), and I want to use the default iSight camera for input, as I don't want to carry around or buy a USB camera if I don't need to.

I am using the example program from OpenCV's user documentation:

```
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"

using namespace cv;

int main(int, char**)
{
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    if(!cap.isOpened()) return -1;

    Mat frame, edges;
    namedWindow("edges",1);
    for(;;)
    {
        cap >> frame;
        cvtColor(frame, edges, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        GaussianBlur(edges, edges, Size(7,7), 1.5, 1.5);
        Canny(edges, edges, 0, 30, 3);
        imshow("edges", edges);
        if(waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this program, the program fails an assertion:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cvtColor, file /Users/dadair/opencv/src/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 3402
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Can anyone explain why this is failing, and what I can do to fix the issue? I am running OpenCV 2.4.6.

Thanks!

Comment: What is says is that the input to cvtColor (i.e. frame) is not a color image (which it expects).

Might be that the capture failed altogether and that `frame` is empty or so.
Try adding `imshow("frame",frame);waitKey();` before the cvtColor line. That will help you debug things.

Comment: Yeah frame is empty, the iSight camera does not even turn on (no green light)

Comment: Did it ever work?  I have seen a problem on my older Macbook where the camera would stop working with OpenCV until rebooted.  Can any other app use the camera after you see this problem?

Comment: There are no problems with the camera itself, I can use it in Skype, etc with zero issues. I just cannot seem to capture from it in openCV, it simply does not turn on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was with the version of openCV used (2.4.6). For access to the iSight camera, you have to use 2.4.5, until whatever bug was introduced in 2.4.6 is fixed. To get 2.4.5 on OSX from Homebrew:

```
$ brew versions opencv
$ cd /usr/local/Library/Taps/homebrew-science
```

checkout git version to older version:

```
$ git checkout ae74fe9 opencv.rb
```

remove the original version of opencv (probably 2.4.6)

```
$ brew unlink opencv
```

install 2.4.5 version:

```
$ brew install opencv
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is just the version of OpenCV, i used the 2.4.5 instead of 2.4.6 and problem resolve...