# Opencv cvCaptureFromCAM not loading any frame on OS X

Tags: c++, linux, macos, opencv

I'm trying to write my own app with OpenCV but i have problem. cvCaptureFromCAM() not loading any frame on my Mac. I tried this way:

```
CvCapture* capture = NULL;

if ((capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(-1)) == NULL) {
    std::cerr << "!!! ERROR: vCaptureFromCAM No camera found\n";
    return;
}

cvNamedWindow("webcam", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
cvMoveWindow("webcam", 50, 50);

IplImage* src = NULL; for (;;) {
    if ((src = cvQueryFrame(capture)) == NULL) {
        std::cerr << "!!! ERROR: vQueryFrame\n";
        break;
    }

    cvShowImage("webcam", &src);
}

cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
```

and this one:

> cv::VideoCapture cap;
>       cap.open(0);
>
> ```
> if( !cap.isOpened() )
> {
>     std::cerr << "***Could not initialize capturing...***\n";
>     std::cerr << "Current parameter's value: \n";
>     return;
> }
>
> cv::Mat frame;
> while(1){
>     cap >> frame;
>     if(frame.empty()){
>         std::cerr<<"frame is empty"<<std::endl;
>         break;
>     }
>
>     cv::imshow("", frame);
>     cv::waitKey(10);
> }
> ```

Those two ways work good on linux, but not on my mac. My built-in camera works in skype and Photo Booth. What i do wrong? Have any ideas?

Comment: Which OpenCV version are you using? `2.4.6` won't work with iSight. I had to install `2.4.5` ([how-to here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19410621/604734)) to make it work.

Comment: And please test `cvCaptureFromCAM(0)` instead of `-1`.